# React router with SEO friendly absolute URLs

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, seo, react-router

I am building a new React based app. SEO is an important aspect for this app. Every page in my app has links to a bunch of other pages. For instance, www.mydomain.com/page1 has these links:

```
<Link to='/page2'>Page 2</Link>
<Link to='/page3'>Page 3</Link>
```

The generated html will be:

```
<a href='/page2'>Page 2</a>
<a href='/page3'>Page 3</a>
```

Routing works perfectly fine in the browser. However, for SEO, I would like to ensure the generated html contains absolute (full) URLs. (Inspired by recommendations from articles like this - https://moz.com/blog/relative-vs-absolute-urls-whiteboard-friday)

This is how I would like my html to look:

```
<a href='www.mydomain.com/page2'>Page 2</a>
<a href='www.mydomain.com/page3'>Page 3</a>
```

Is there a way I can achieve this?

Thanks in advance!